# How to build an if statement with the following URL param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following to enable users to sort comments by date (ASC), date (DESC) and vote:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                        :per_page => 5).order(params[:order_by])
    @comment = @post.comments.build
  end
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<div class="comments-tabs">
  <span><%= link_to 'Votes', post_path(@post, :order_by => "total_votes DESC") %></span>
  <span><%= link_to 'Date (ASC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at ASC") %></span>
  <span><%= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at DESC") %></span>
</div>
```

the URL ends up looking like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/59?order_by=total_votes+DESC
http://localhost:3000/posts/59?order_by=created_at+ASC
http://localhost:3000/posts/59?order_by=created_at+DESC
```

I would like to create an if statement to add a class to the current tab. For example:

```
    http://localhost:3000/posts/59?order_by=created_at+ASC


  <span class="comment-tab"><%= link_to 'Votes', post_path(@post, :order_by => "total_votes DESC") %></span>
  <span class="comment-tab current"><%= link_to 'Date (ASC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at ASC") %></span>
  <span class="comment-tab><%= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at DESC") %></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current_page? method to determine whether the user is viewing a certain page and apply an html class based on that.

Here's an example:

```
 %ul
    %li{:class => "#{current_page?(root_path) ? "selected" : ""}"}= link_to content_tag(:span, "Home"), root_path
    %li{:class => "#{current_page?(birth_certificate_path) ? "selected" : ""}"}= link_to content_tag(:span, "Birth Certificates"), birth_certificate_path
    %li{:class => "#{current_page?(marriage_certificate_path) ? "selected" : ""}"}= link_to content_tag(:span, "Marriage Certificates"), marriage_certificate_path
    %li{:class => "#{current_page?(death_certificate_path) ? "selected" : ""}"}= link_to content_tag(:span, "Death Certificates"), death_certificate_path
```

Comment: current_page looks at the request object I believe, which does contain the params hash, but isn't required for current_page to know what page you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `link_to_unless_current` method of [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org)

```
<%=
    link_to_unless_current("Comment", { :controller => "comments", :action => "new" }) do
       link_to("Go back", { :controller => "posts", :action => "index" })
    end
 %>
```

Comment: link_to_unless_current: "Creates a link tag ... unless the current request URI is the same as the links, in which case only the name is returned." I don't think that's what @alexchenco is asking for. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current

Comment: "...(or the given block is yielded, if one exists)" The block could be useful in other cases, but in this case, OP needs to conditionally modify the class of the link's parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. You really got me thinking. I've wanted to accomplish something similar in my own project, to refactor some smelly if statements that were used to style a div or li differently when its containing link was equal to the current page.

I wrote this in coffee-flavored jQuery. Give it a try.

app/assets/javascripts/current_tab.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.comment-tab').each ->
    if $(this).children('a').first().attr('href') is window.location.href
      $(this).addClass('current')
```

Change post_path to post_url in the view, and it should work.

app/views/posts/show.html.haml

```
.comments-tabs
  %span= link_to 'Votes',       post_url(@post, order_by: 'total_votes DESC')
  %span= link_to 'Date (ASC)',  post_url(@post, order_by: 'created_at ASC')
  %span= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_url(@post, order_by: 'created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="comments-tabs">
  <span><%= link_to 'Votes', post_path(@post, :order_by => "total_votes DESC"), {}, {:class => "#{params[:order_by] == 'total_votes+DESC' ? 'comment_tab current' : 'comment_tab'}"} %></span>
  <span><%= link_to 'Date (ASC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at ASC"), {}, {:class => "#{params[:order_by] == 'created_at+ASC' ? 'comment_tab current' : 'comment_tab'}"}  %></span>
  <span><%= link_to 'Date (DESC)', post_path(@post, :order_by => "created_at DESC"), {}, {:class => "#{params[:order_by] == 'created_at+DESC' ? 'comment_tab current' : 'comment_tab'}"} %></span>
</div>
```

Untested.